# How do I remove this redundant icon in my app switcher forever?

Tags: macos, mac, productivity, finder

For some unknown reason, I sometimes have two Firefox icons in my app switcher, one is always stuck on the left, slowing or confusing me when I try to switch between apps:

[image]

It slows me down enormously when switching between apps and I have no idea why it does that. It looks like some obtrusive feature meant to blend personal browsing history with professional workflows (what could go wrong?) which should be optional but never enabled by default.

**How do I get rid of this redundant duplicate icon in my app switcher?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like a Handoff icon, this is a *"feature"* that allows you to open an application that you have open on another device - as long as that device is nearby, both devices are logged into the same Apple ID and have Handoff turned on. Judging from the look of the icon, it seems like you have a nearby desktop computer with Firefox as the frontmost app - is this the case?

If you don't like this, you can turn it off - search for Handoff in System Settings.